# How to disable some criteria for product sort order in OpenCart?

Tags: sorting, opencart

By default there are:

1. Default
2. Name (A-Z)
3. ...
4. Model (A-Z)
5. Model (Z-A)

I want disable **Default** and few others.

Is there any tool in administrative panel to do that or do I need to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn’t find any tool in administrative panel, so in order to disable sort by "**Default**" I had to do it programmatically in following way:

1. in file /admin/catalog/controller/product/category.php

   `/*$data['sorts'][] = array(
   'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'), 
   'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',
   'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' .   $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC' $url)
   );*/`
2. in file /admin/catalog/language/english/product/category.php

   `//$_['text_default']      = 'Default';`

It is working at this moment.